# CSS When tabbing through page

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have this site where some keyboard only people will use. On some certain elements nothing shows when tabbed onto them. the element is as follows

`<div id="NBSCustomiseHomepageLink"><a href="http://my.nbsdev.co.uk/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx"><div id="NBSCustomiseHomepageButton">Edit your profile</div></a></div>`

I have added an outline to get the correct border I want for when it is tabbed onto it. The problem I face is that I don't know how to make it so it comes on when its tabbed onto any ideas?
css code is

```
#NBSCustomiseHomepageLink{
    outline:black dotted thin;
}
```

Comment: what is your current CSS or code? Do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am right it `:focus`  and [Fiddle is here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a9qs8c9z/)